# Tapping Into Car Battery

Tags: batteries, automotive

I was wondering if when I needed to run a cable from the negative terminal of my battery when running the positive inside my car for powering a CB radio. I know this seems like a dumb question but I have not been able to find a definite answer online.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd ask another Ham. They do this all day long. Hmm. Here's one: http://www.k0bg.com/wiring.html and another: http://www.k6ria.net/study%20materials/mobile/Mobile%20Installation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quite likely 100% of all vehicles on the road, the negative side of the battery is firmly connected to the chassis/frame/body of the vehicle.  It is very common to use the metal body of the vehicle as a convenient path to "ground".  You are quite safe assuming that the metal body is ground by definition.

Ref: http://www.w8ji.com/negative_lead_to_battery.htm

Comment: I've actually worked on cars with positive tied to the chassis/frame. But that was 40 years ago. Used to be that I had to be careful about "jumping" one car from another. But you are right that it's rather safe today to assume negative to chassis. Haven't seen one of those old cars around in decades.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that all the old positive-ground vehicles are "trailer queens" or sitting in museums and @Austin is not desecrating one of them by installing a CB radio.

Comment: If you were to have a positive ground auto, you would most likely have to isolate the rig from the frame as to avoid shorting things out. That would be a challenge an it might be better replacing the auto, as the antenna carries a ground.